# Can't turn element of a list into an integer

Tags: python

I got a list in my code, it looks like. `L = ['Nickname', '35']`
When i try to `i = int(L[2])` it catches an exception

```
exceptions.ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
      namesplitted = line.split()
      lnum += 1 
      truename = namesplitted[0]
      kills = namesplitted[1]
      print kills
      >>> 34
      i = int(kills[1])
```

Comment: List indices are 0-based . Try `L[1]`.

Comment: My bad, its actually L[1]

Comment: Can you provide some more of the code, and also double check the sample data you're using? Trying this out on my machine (Python 3.3.2) this seems to work just fine with the data and example you gave.

Comment: Sorry for that, posted actual code, still getting a same exception

Comment: Does `kills` equal 34?

Comment: Kills are. print namesplitted >>>['Architektor_kun', '34']

Comment: I can't seem to understand if that is `kills` or `namesplitted`. Can you just do `print kills` and post the result?

Comment: I got strange exception again, i think the problem is in that 'byte 0xbd' print kills >>>34          exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 2):

It's because your number `'35'` is located at `L[1]`. List Indices start from 0 in Python. So the first element is `L[0]`, the second is `L[1]` and so on.

Your list is probably `L = ['Nickname', '35', '']`

```
>>> L = ['Nickname', '35', '']
>>> int(L[2])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#142>", line 1, in <module>
    int(L[2])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>> int(L[1])
35
```

Comment: Nope, its actually L[1] in my code, and i still got the error

Comment: Are you sure that the list you gave in the question is your actual list?

Comment: You gave us your `L` list, but the error seems to be on the `kills` list. Can you please check your `kills` list and post that here?